# Only variables should be assigned by reference with function

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use old version of Codeigniter framework. With new version of php I am gettings this error:
`Only variables should be assigned by reference`

I am wondering if this is safe bugfix:
Changing:

```
 $this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();
```

to

```
$assign = is_loaded();    
$this->_base_classes =& $assign;
```

Is that the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please see this url

> https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/904

You can go to `file: system/core/Loader.php`
Then
`file: system/core/Common.php` Line 190 there should be:

```
function &is_loaded($class = '')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an codeigniter bug in which the old version does not support anymore the mysql.

You can go to file: system/core/Loader.php Then file: system/core/Common.php Line 190 there should be:

```
//function is_loaded($class = '') >>> Edit this one like the expression below

  function &is_loaded($class = '')

function &is_loaded($class = '')
```

After that go to file: application/config/database.php and change the following below:

```
//$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; >>> Edit this one like the expression below.

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

I hope it works

Comment: You should edit your post to include code formatting. Also, does this change the actual SQL driver to a different database driver?

Answer (score 1):

remove this in line 150 from `system/core/Loader.php`

`$this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();`
..

Answer (score 1):

Go to File: system\core you will find a file named as Common.php
open the file and go to line 190
where you will find `function is_loaded($class = '')`
just replace it by this line of code `function &is_loaded($class = '')`

Comment: Not a good idea to change the file directly in the core. The proper way is to copy that file into application/core/MY_Common.php and change it there leaving the original one intact.

Comment: Why do you feel its not a good idea?? I have tried it myself it didn't give any issue for me.

Comment: Because if you ever need to upgrade that version of codeigniter to a newer one having the system files modified will give you an extra headache.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> $this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();

to

> $this->_base_classes = $this->is_loaded();

Worked for me.