# codeigniter sql backup works fine in local server but in live it shows error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: **Only variables should be assigned by reference**

**this is my controller code **

```
public function data_backup()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $prefs = array('format' => 'zip','filename' => 'nirmithi.sql');
    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 
    $db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
    $save = 'Backup/'.$db_name;
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file($save, $backup); 
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download($db_name, $backup);
}
```

Comment: why would you need a reference here? `$backup =& $`

Comment: This may be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789659/only-variables-should-be-assigned-by-reference-with-function

Comment: am just using codeigniter library thats it and i just removed '&' and its works great thank you for your replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove & in this line try it

```
$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
```